# How to view more than one layers balloon description box in Google Earth

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kml, google-earth

This may be a lot simpler than I am making it, but I have racked my brain over this for some time:

I have two shapefiles in ArcMap - 
The first is a county wide layer made up of hundreds of postcode sector polygons, each showing an average house price. This has been categorized and colour coded into seven categories.

The second is a layer with a select few regions within the county (as polygons) which are thought to be good locations for a new development which I want with no fill but a black outline.

Now I have exported these using the layer to kml tool with no problems and they keep the symbology and formatting I want, however when looking at the description bubble when I click on an area it only shows me the information for the average house price data.

Is there a way that I can view both that and the name of the location thought to be a good for a new development, whilst keeping the formatting of both?

[image: Please note that the output area is not the black polygon it is the postcode district]

Answer (score 1):

If it is like GoogleEarth, when you click it will ONLY display the uppermost layer  in the pop-up box. To have a different layer display, you will need to turn off house price data and make sure the layer you want to display is the upper most layer.

You could do some table joins create a kml file off those joins to make the pop-up have all info in one display.